# read file to the very end

Tags: java, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whole text file to a String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849692/whole-text-file-to-a-string-in-java)

How can I read a text file to the very end?

Actually I need to output the whole file into the screen, therefore I think that I need to get the whole data in the file as an `String`.

Comment: Then you can just read it all in a string directly using @beerbajay's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)'s [`readFileToString()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29) method.

```
String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("file.txt"), "utf-8");
```