# read complete file without using loop in java

Tags: java, file, io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a Java String from the contents of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file)
>   [Whole text file to a String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849692/whole-text-file-to-a-string-in-java)

I am trying to read the contents of a file using FileReader . But i want to read the file without reading a line by line . Is it possible to read the whole file without loop.
I am using the following code

```
 try
 {
     File ff=new File("abc.txt");
     FileReader fr=new FileReader(ff);

     String s;
     while(br.read()!=-1)
     {
          s=br.readLine();
     }
 }

 catch(Exception ex)
 {
     ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: This code won't compile to begin with.

Comment: There is a one-line Java 11 solution to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52301018/942774

Answer (score 144, accepted):

If the file is **small**, you can read the whole data once:

```
File file = new File("a.txt");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
fis.read(data);
fis.close();

String str = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Does not work for InputStream's s.a. Android assets (no length)

Comment: How small is "small"?

Comment: @silver Entire content of the file will be stored in memory. So, avoid reading 5GB files like this :-)

Comment: When I do this, the string `str` ends up with a lot of 0 characters (&#0;) at the end. Not sure why.

Comment: Note: `file.length()` may return 0 for files under `/proc`. And in those cases this snippet will return an empty string.

Comment: Also `read` might not fill the entire buffer. It might work in practice with most JREs, but there's no guarantee in the API.

Answer (score 212):

Java 7 one line solution

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

or

```
 String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("file")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Can't find that Files in Android.

Comment: Not all Java answers have to be suited to Android, @akauppi! Just look for a solution that Android supports from another answer!

Comment: `String text = Files.readString(Paths.get("file"));` is even shorter, assuming that you want a UTF-8 String output.

Comment: And if you already have the File object, you can do `file.toPath()` inside `readAllBytes`

Comment: Important for Android: `Call requires API level 26: java.nio.file.Files#readAllBytes` - same thing for `readString`.

Comment: @EagterrianKnight What `Files` is that exactly? `readString` doesn't exist for the `java.nio.file.Files` one in Java 8.

Comment: Related answer (more details): https://stackoverflow.com/a/326440/9549068

Answer (score 36):

You can try using [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) if you are using JDK5 or higher.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);  
scan.useDelimiter("\\Z");  
String content = scan.next();
```

Or you can also use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

```
String data = Files.toString(new File("path.txt"), Charsets.UTF8);
```

Comment: Note that the scanner should be closed after use.

Comment: `String data = Files.toString(new File("path.txt"), Charsets.UTF_8);`. Just a small typo. :-)

Comment: This code with `Scanner` only read first 1024 bytes from file. Look at source code. It read buffer and check it with this regexp. This always valid - then it return all buffer content. By default buffer have size of 1024 bytes.

Comment: This is BAD approach.  The correct solution (for Java 1.7 and higher) is `Files.readAllLines()`.  For legacy JREs, `FileInputStream.read()` is probably best.  I'm not sure if it's portable to all platforms (i.e. Ctl-Z is recognized everywhere), and it 's easy to miss doing a `Scanner.close()`.

Answer (score 36):

If you are using Java 5/6, you can use [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) for read file to string. The class [**`org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`**](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) contais several method for read files.

e.g. using the method `FileUtils#readFileToString`:

```
File file = new File("abc.txt");
String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
```

Comment: This is probably the easiest solution using a 3rd-party lib.

Comment: Minimal code to write; Many more libraries to add to project.

Comment: The method readFileToString(File) from the type FileUtils is deprecated

Answer (score 22):

Since Java 11 you can do it even simpler:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;

Files.readString(Path path);
Files.readString​(Path path, Charset cs)
```

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readString(java.nio.file.Path)