# Read complete file without looping in android

Tags: java, android, cordova

i need a solution  for reading a text file which was stored in internal storage.
i don't want to read it line by line. without use looping how to read a complete text file and store it into a string.

```
BufferedReader br;
String line;
String data = "";
// String text="";
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "queue_mgr.txt")));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    br.close();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read complete file without using loop in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169661/read-complete-file-without-using-loop-in-java)

Comment: I think that solution won't work in Android.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? There will be looping at some level. Even if there were an API to copy a text file, the implementation of that API would have looping of some sort. If you want something more efficient, you might be able to using a large byte buffer instead of text. See my answer below.

Comment: i need to send json object to server.

Comment: it will read internal storage and converted into json object.i need to know how to read complete filw without read line by line

Comment: Any reading file will be read line by line, maybe you will not see it at a high level, but the class will do just that. However why would you not read it line by line?

Comment: Because am using for loop for json object the text file will be convert as a json object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a large byte buffer and gain some efficiency:

```
try
{
  InputStream in = new FileInputStream (from);
  OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream (to);

  // Transfer bytes from in to out
  byte[] buf = new byte[1024 * 10]; // 5MB would be about 500 iterations
  int len;
  while ((len = in.read (buf)) > 0)
    out.write (buf, 0, len);

  in.close ();
  out.close ();
  }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
  ...
}
catch (IOException e)
{
  ...
}
```