# GLSL: Illegal non-directive after #

Tags: java, opengl, glsl

I am trying to learn opengl through java using LWJGL. When trying to compile shader programs I get the error

```
java.lang.Exception: Error compiling shading code: 0:1(1): preprocessor error: Illegal non-directive after #
```

I know nothing about C only Java.

```
#version 330

layout (location =0) in vec3 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}


#version 330

out vec4 fragColor;

main()
{

    fragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
}
```

These are my two shader files.

this is the code that loads them:

```
public void createVertexShader(String code) throws Exception{
        vertexShaderId = createShader(code,GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    }

    public void createFragmentShader(String code) throws Exception{
        fragmentShaderId = createShader(code,GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    }

    protected int createShader(String code, int type) throws Exception{
        int shaderId = glCreateShader(type);
        if(shaderId == 0){
            throw new Exception("error createing shader. type: "+type);
        }

        glShaderSource(shaderId,code);
        glCompileShader(shaderId);

        if(glGetShaderi(shaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == 0){
            throw new Exception("Error compiling shading code: "+glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderId,1024));
        }

        glAttachShader(programId, shaderId);

        return shaderId;
    }



public static String loadResource(String fileName) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try (InputStream in = Utils.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in, "UTF-8")) {

            while(scanner.hasNext()){
                result.append( scanner.next() );
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
```

I don't understand what I need to do to compile this simple file.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load a shader file!"
                                       + System.lineSeparator() + ex.getMessage());
        }
        String source = builder.toString();
        return source;
```

I've changed it to this which is a shader loader that works in another program. Yet here I am still getting the same unexcpected New Identifier.
What the hell?

Comment: Yes then it says: 0:1(1): error: syntax error, unexpected NEW_IDENTIFIER

Answer (score 3):

The way you read the file discards all whitespaces including newlines. You get the error because the shader compiler effectively reads something like 
`version330layout(....`

Since whitespaces and newlines are important for a glsl shader stop reading whole files with a Scanner (or at least don't read it word by word). Have a look at [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169661/read-complete-file-without-using-loop-in-java) on how to read whole files without loosing whitespaces.

Comment: Thank you, I tried loading the file a different way that works in another program. I am still getting the same unexcpected new Identifier error