# Loading multiple properties sets from single file for multiple class instances

Tags: java, properties, instance

I have a class of which I need a different instance if one of its attributes changes. These changes are read at runtime from a property file.
I would like to have a single file detailing the properties of all the single instances:

```
------------
name=Milan
surface=....
------------
name=Naples
surface=....
```

How can I load each set of properties in a different Property class (maybe creating a `Properties[]`)? Is there a Java built in method to do so?
Should I manually parse it, how could create an InputStream anytime I find the division String among the sets?

```
ArrayList<Properties> properties = new ArrayList<>();
if( whateverItIs.nextLine() == "----" ){
        InputStream limitedInputStream = next-5-lines ;
        properties.add(new Properties().load(limitedInputStream));
}
```

Something like above. And, by the way, any constructor method which directly creates the class from a file?

EDIT: any pointing in the right direction to look it for myself would be fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, read the whole file as a single string. Then use `split` and `StringReader`.

```
String propertiesFile = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "utf-8");
String[] propertyDivs = propertiesFile.split("----");
ArrayList<Properties> properties = new ArrayList<Properties>();

for (String propertyDiv : propertyDivs) {
     properties.add(new Properties().load(new StringReader(propertyDiv)));
}
```

The example above uses `apache commons-io` library for file to `String` one-liner, because Java does not have such a built-in method. However, reading file can be easily implemented using standard Java libraries, see [Whole text file to a String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849692/whole-text-file-to-a-string-in-java)

Comment: I use to access my file getting the resource. Is this the right approach:
`File f = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("cities.prop").getPath());`

Comment: @Vale It is OK in my opinion. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1318386/3899583